# updatedb can not create temporary file for a custom database file

Tags: linux, permissions, suse, updatedb

I am trying to create a custom `mlocate` db for my home directory. When running the `updatedb` it complains about inability to open a temporary file.

```
55;~/>uname -a
Linux yoga 4.12.14-lp151.28.59-default #1 SMP Wed Aug 5 10:58:34 UTC 2020 (337e42e) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
56;~/>updatedb --version
updatedb (mlocate) 0.26
...
57;~/>updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.home-mlocate.db -U ~/
updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/home/<user>/.home-mlocate.db'
```

Prepending `updatedb` with `sudo` or running as root does not change the outcome. Running simply `sudo updatedb` without any arguments succeeds.

More generally unless the database is the default one `updatedb` can not create temporary file:

```
yoga:~ # /usr/bin/whoami
root
yoga:~ # /usr/bin/updatedb ; echo $?
0
yoga:~ # /usr/bin/updatedb -o /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db ; echo $?
0
yoga:~ # /usr/bin/updatedb -o /var/lib/mlocate/custom-mlocate.db ; echo $?
/usr/bin/updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/custom-mlocate.db'
1
yoga:~ # /usr/bin/strace /usr/bin/updatedb -o /var/lib/mlocate/custom-mlocate.db 2>&1 1>\dev\null | grep "openat.*custom-mlocate.db"
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/mlocate/custom-mlocate.db", O_RDWR) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/mlocate/custom-mlocate.db.6JiH9O", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
yoga:~ #
```

My operating system is openSUSE Leap 15.1 and my `/home` directory is on an ext4 file system.

What is the problem and how it is to be resolved?

Comment: You write "prepending `updatedb` with `sudo` ... does not change the outcome. Running simply `sudo updatedb` succeeds". Where's the difference? Can you clarify?

Comment: @eblock What I meant is that running `updatedb` as a root and without any arguments runs successfully and updates the default database. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: You might try running the command with `strace` to see if it throws any light on *why* the temporary file creation fails

Comment: The error message indicates that you do not have write permission in the directory where you're writing the output database. Did you write the command exactly as shown in the question, and if so, are you able to create other files under `~/`?

Comment: @Kusalananda It seems so, but why? It is my home dir and I can access files in it any way I like. There seem to be no problem outside of `updatedb`. Also running as root has the same access problem.

Comment: Run the command with `strace` as steeldriver suggested and see what you can find out about the call to `mkstemp()` from the output.

Comment: @steeldriver `strace updatedb -o ~/.home-mlocate.db -U ~/` gives `...openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/<user>/.home-mlocate.db.ZvgxzG", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)...`. And `sudo strace updatedb -o ~/.home-mlocate.db -U ~/` gives the same.  I can write to `~/` no problem.

Comment: @Kusalananda There is no call to `mkstemp()` in the output from `strace`. I think the offending line is as in my previous comment.

Comment: @R.Matveev Well, the `mkstemp()` call generates a call to `openat()` later, and that's what you see in the output from `strace` so that's ok.

Comment: @Kusalananda How do I analyse the problem further? The corresponding call `openat()` for the tmp file succeeds when running `updatedb` without arguments.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have created an entirely new user. Logged in as the new user in the corresponding home dir the problem persists.

Comment: What type of Linux is this, exactly? what filesystem do your users' home directories reside on (ex. output of `findmnt -T ~/` or equivalent)

Comment: @steeldriver opensuse Leap 15.1. is the distro. `/home` is on ext4. After some experimentation: `updatedb` is not able to create tmp file once `-o` option is given, regardless of the location of the file and permissions of the process. E.g. running as root and in the dir `/var/lib/mlocate`, where the default database sits.

Comment: Is SELinux installed on your system? Have you checked your logs for security-related messages?

Comment: Yes, selinux is installed. Which logs shall I look into?

Comment: According to the [openSUSE documentation](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book.security/cha-selinux.html#sec-selinux-troubleshoot), it should be `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: @fra-san I solved it. Thanks so much. I would never figure it out by myself and would just go crazy.

Comment: Thank you everybody who spent time on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was suggested by @fra-san the problem was caused by security policies. The solution is

1. Make sure you have audit daemon running and `audit2allow`
   installed.
   For opensuse audit daemon is in the package `audit`,
   and `audit2allow` is in `policycoreutils`. Install if not present and
   start the daemon as root

```
systemctl start auditd
```

2. Run the offending program, e.g. `updatedb -o ~/custom-mlocate.db -U ~/`
   as a normal user. The rest should be executed logged in as root (bad)
   or prepending each line with `sudo` (good).
3. Examine the last few lines of `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

   ```
   tail -n 20 /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep -i denied
   ```

   You are interested in the line that starts with
   `type=AVC` and where
   the name of the offending command appears.
   There are two possibilities:

- The line contains `avc:  denied`. Your system uses SELinux.
- The line contains `apparmor="DENIED"`. It means your system uses AppArmor for security.

If it is AppArmor, consult AppArmor manuals.
E.g.
https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book.security/part-apparmor.html
for OpenSuse.

For SELinux:

4. Copy the line you identified in step 3 to a separate file.
   E.g.

   ```
   tail -n 20 /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep -i "denied.*updatedb" > /var/log/audit/audit-partial-tmp.log
   ```

   Check that it is OK

   ```
   cat /var/log/audit/audit-partial-tmp.log
   ```

   and

   ```
   audit2allow -w -i /var/log/audit/audit-partial-tmp.log
   ```
5. Create SELinux module

   ```
   audit2allow -i /var/log/audit/audit-partial-tmp.log -M custom-selinux-module
   ```
6. Make new policy active

   ```
   semodule -i custom-selinux-module.pp
   ```
7. Run the program as a normal user to check whether it is ok. E.g.

   ```
   updatedb -o ~/custom-mlocate.db -U ~/
   ```
8. Cleanup

   ```
   rm /var/log/audit/audit-partial-tmp.log custom-selinux-module.pp
   ```

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution an thanks for taking the time to self-answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

If you have write permission to the database file, but not to the directory in which it was created, then you can workaround this issue by writing the database somewhere else where you do have directory-write permission and then copying it to the final file location e.g.

```
updatedb -o /myhomedir/mydb.db
cp /myhomedir/mydb.db /somespeciallocation/mydb.db
```